# Filezilla not transferring files completely

Tags: ftp, csv, filezilla

We use Filezilla FTP client for transferring very high volume CSV files to our client sites.

For example: 883MB file.

The CSV on our end shows 883MB. The CSV at the receiving end after transfer shows 883MB. But the client says data is missing from the csv they received. We see it on our end. THis has been happening repeatedly for quite some time now and needless to say, the client is frustrated.

The console log on Filezilla does not show any errors or aborts.

The file is generated from a SAS program running on Server A which is a VDI.
SAS writes the final output to a shared location on NAS drive, say, Server B.
For some reason, I cannot invoke Filezilla on Server A directly.

So, I login to Server C which has a working filezilla client. From Server C, I ftp the file from a shared drive to B.

Anyone know what is going on here?

Forgot to mention: The remote server is a Linux server and I am on Windows Servers. So its a Windows -> Linux transfer.

Comment: Have you tried check-summing the files on each end of the transfer?

Comment: @DavidPostill thanks for responding. No, I didnt try that. How would I do that? Also, forgot to mention this is a Windows - Linux transfer. Will that change things?

Comment: Well Windows and Linux use different EOL characters for plain text files (like CSV).

Comment: If the file is created by a program on a Linux environment and opened with a program on a Windows system it is possible that some characters are misinterpreted or lost. Regarding check sum verification read here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_file_verification

Answer (score 0):

This is a known problem since 2008. It's suspected to do with NAT configuration. See https://forum.filezilla-project.org/viewtopic.php?t=5402
It's still not solved as I am still having this issue. I FTP files from a NAS. You can use another free FTP software and it does the job.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still looking for a solution-

In FileZilla, navigate to **File** -> **Site Manager** -> **[Your Server]** -> **Transfer Settings** tab. Check the box for "**Limit the number of simultaneous connections**" and set it to **1**.

[image: Screenshot]